# Can't resolve NPM Typescript index.ts package export?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I have created this [typescript validation library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fireflysemantics/validator) and I'm attempting to create a [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/validator-demo?file=index.ts).

The import:

```
import { IsDefined } from "@fireflysemantics/validator";
```

Is not resolving.  I have included `index.ts` in the root of the module and it exports `IsDefined` like this:

```
export { IsDefined } from "./decorators/IsDefined";
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to includes `"types": "index.d.ts"` in `package.json`.  The samples are updated and it works now.